# Microsoft word 2010 text wrap in table

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I noticed that I have two tables in my word document. One I made and one I copied it from somewhere. The one I copied, when I resize my table, the cell text automatically wraps around if the width is not enough. (Not hyphenation, just wraps). The one I copied does not do that. However, I don't notice anything different between the two. The row size specifications in both are unchecked. Where is the setting for this?

Comment: Its not AutoFit > AutoFit to contents is it? You can find it if you right-click on a cell.

Comment: can you show us some screenshot?

Comment: can you tell us both tables are getting resized?

Comment: Yes both tables are getting re-sized and they react differently. Unfortunately I wiped out my other table because I am in a hurry so I don't have a screen shot to show for now. I will post it again if I encounter it in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Right-click on the cell.  Choose "Auto-Fit" and then choose "Fixed column width".

Answer (score 1):

One possible explanation for the apparent non-wrapping behavior is that the text is actually wrapping, but the formatting of the cell has a margin outside of the cell boundaries. In the example below, the two columns are equal width and contain the same text, but the text on the right has a paragraph right indent outside the table boundary (see ruler bar mark after the 7). You would highlight the cell text and manually move the indent back within the cell margins or apply a style that overwrites the right indent.

[image: Cell paragraph example]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by changing the paragraph's right indentation from blank to 0.